# Does the sandwich-estimate eliminate heteroskedasticity in a model residuals versus fitted plot, or simply make the estimation robust to heteroskedas?

Tags: residuals, heteroscedasticity, generalized-estimating-equations, sandwich

Does the sandwich-estimator/Huber-White/GEE eliminate heteroskedasticity in a residuals versus fitted plot, or simply make the model robust to it?

Comment: Neither.  The goal iin the first instance is more honest standard errors with consequences for inference. The parameter estimates and so the residuals and fitted are exactly the same as otherwise. (As always there is some controversy around  the first part of this comment.)

Comment: The name Eicker should be mentioned alongside Huber and White.